# Equality issues in javascript

Tags: javascript

I don't understand why the last line in this code snippet returns false. Isn't it the same as the line above?

```
const Statuses = Object.freeze({
  UNKNOWN : 0,
  OK      : 1,
  ERROR   : 2,
  STOPPED : 3
});

class myStatus extends Object{
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.status_id = Statuses.UNKNOWN;
  }
  valueOf(){
    return this.status_id;
  }
  getStatus(){
    return this.status_id;
  }
}

var a = new myStatus();
a.status_id = Statuses.ERROR;
console.log(a == Statuses.ERROR);
console.log(a.getStatus() === Statuses.ERROR);
console.log(a.valueOf() === Statuses.ERROR); //Isn't this the same as the line bellow?
console.log(a === Statuses.ERROR); //Why is this false but the rest are true?
```

http://jsbin.com/ritumesegi/edit?js,console

I get `a == Statuses.ERROR` being true, but shouldn't the rest give the same result? Especially the last 2. Isn't

```
a === Statuses.ERROR
```

the same as

```
a.valueOf() === Statuses.ERROR
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `===`, neither value is implicitly converted to anything else.

So in your snippet, `STATUSES.ERROR` is simply the primitive number value `2`, whereas `a` is an instance of the `myStatus` class. Since there is no conversion when comparing with `===`, it's not surprising that they aren't the same, since one is a primitive value and the other is not.

Comment: So when using `===` it doesn't actually call the `valueOf` function?

Comment: @dsat yep! That is correct. With `===` there won't be any implicit method calls, unlike when using `==` (which as you guessed will implicitly call `valueOf` for non-primitives).

Answer (score 4):

Simply because they are not same type, check below :

```
console.log(typeof(Statuses.ERROR)); // "number"
console.log(typeof(a) ); // "object"
```

**Difference:**
`==` evaluate values only.
`===` evaluate values and types.

**Reference:**
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_operators.asp

http://jsbin.com/jaquzikonu/edit?js,console

Comment: Yes but why is this `a == Statuses.ERROR` true? If this is true, it means it actually gets the value by running `valueOf`.

Comment: Because you have used `===` which means should be same type.

Comment: Yeap. I assumed the type would be that of the value returned by `valueOf`. But apparently `valueOf` isn't even called when using `===`. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

**a** is a myStatus object, so **a !== 2**, because it is an object.

**a.valueOf()** is 2.